# Selectize.js - How to make it update options and select last one after creating with ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selectize.js

I have a Rails app with Listings that belongs to a Company. I want to allow the user to directly create a new Company from the Listing#new form by using ajax and the Selectize.js plugin.

My issue is, after creating the Company, Selectize.js will neither update the options nor select the last created Company. I've been reading the API for hours and checked dozens of other SO answers, but the code accepted in most of them doesn't seem to work for my case.

My listing#new form:

```
<%= form_for @listing, remote: true do |f| %>
  # Some other fields

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label "Company / Location" %>
    <%= collection_select(:listing, :company_id, @companies, :id, :name, { prompt: true }, { required: true, class: 'selectize'}) %>
  </div>

  # Some other fields
  <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-large' %>
<% end %>
```

The CompaniesController.rb

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  # Some other actions

  def create
    @company = current_user.companies.new(company_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company created' } 
        format.json { render json: { company: @company } }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: { errors: @company.errors.full_messages } }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My application.js:

```js
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  let $companies = $("select#listing_company_id").selectize({
    valueField: "id",
    labelField: "name",
    create: function(input, cb) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/companies",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          company: { name: input }
        },
        success: function(res) {
          console.log(res);
          if (!res.errors) {
            cb({ id: res.id, name: res.name });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**Current Behavior**

The Company is properly created on the server, and the server properly responds with the JSON with the created company's id and name, but the Select option defaults back to the placeholder "Please select" option and it does not show the new company until I reload the page.

**Desired Behavior**

After creating the Company, the select field will update with all the options and will automatically select the new company.

**Questions**

So, I'm having a hard time figuring out two things:

1. How to make Selectize update the option list with the newly created Company after receiving the data from the server?
2. How to make the option be selected after creation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after almost 6 hours battling with this issue (and going back and forth drafting this question) , I actually found the solution and it was really simple:

In the CompanyController.rb, instead of returning:

```rb
format.json { render json: { company: @company } }
```

I changed to:

```
format.json { render json: { id: @company.id, name: @company.name }
```

Exactly matching the data format that Selectize was expecting. It worked perfectly after that.